# WMI: PCIExpress

Tags: wmi, pci-e

Does anybody know the way to get devices attached to PCI Express slots by using WMI?

I've been using Win32_PnPEntity class, but I can't make a distinguish between PCI and PCI Express devices.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is not a WMI class or property to detect the PCI Express devices directly in a reliable way, but as workaround you can check for the `PCI Express` string in the `Description` property of the [`Win32_PnPEntity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class.

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity Where Description LIKE "%PCI Express%"
```